# Create XML from a / separated string

Tags: java, list, compare

Following is a  Map element
i need to create a xslt from this.

```
  {    /output1/output1/output1/output13=/input12/bunny,  
    /output1/output1/output1/output14=/input12/no,    
    /output1/output1/output13/output12=/input12/ok,   
    /output1/output1/output13/output16=/input12/honey

     }
```

how should i compare the each element of key element  with each element of the next key element?

package mig;

```
import java.io.File;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.HashMap;
 import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
 import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
 import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
 import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
 import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
 import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
 import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
 import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
  import org.w3c.dom.Document;
  import org.w3c.dom.Element;
  import org.w3c.dom.Attr;
 import org.w3c.dom.Node;
 import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
```

public class CreateXSLT {

```
public static final String xmlFilePath = "D:/xmlfile.xml";

public void  createXSLT(ArrayList<String> SourceValues,ArrayList<String> SourceTypes,ArrayList<String> TargetValues,ArrayList<String> TargetTypes,ArrayList<String> Transform)
{


    try {

        Map<String, String> yourMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

        for(int x=0;x<TargetValues.size();x++)
        {
            yourMap.put(TargetValues.get(x),SourceValues.get(x));
        }

        Map<String, String> sortedMap = new TreeMap<String, String>(yourMap);

        System.out.println(sortedMap);

        Set<Entry<String, String>> entires =sortedMap.entrySet();
        Set<String> keyset = sortedMap.keySet();
        System.out.println(keyset);


    DocumentBuilderFactory documentFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

    DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

    Document document = documentBuilder.newDocument();

    Element root = document.createElement("xsl:stylesheet");

    document.appendChild(root);

    Element root1 = document.createElement("xsl:template");
    root.appendChild(root1);

    Attr attr = document.createAttribute("match");
    attr.setValue("/");
    root1.setAttributeNode(attr);




    Element empDiffNxt = null; 
    Element  empDiff = null; 


int nodeLength = keyset.size(); 
System.out.println("TARGET sIZE: " + nodeLength);



    for(String key : keyset)
    {

        ArrayList<String> check = new ArrayList<String>();

        check.add(key);
        String[] Tg = key.split("/");



     for (int m=1; m< Tg.length; m++)

     {




         if( m == 1 )
         {
          empDiffNxt = document.createElement(Tg[m]);
         root1.appendChild(empDiffNxt);
         }
         else 
         {
              empDiff = document.createElement(Tg[m]);
              empDiffNxt.appendChild(empDiff);
              empDiffNxt= empDiff;
         }




     }

     Element emp1 = document.createElement("xsl:value-of");

        empDiffNxt.appendChild(emp1);

        Attr attr1 = document.createAttribute("select");


        attr1.setValue(sortedMap.get(key));

        emp1.setAttributeNode(attr1);



}






    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
    DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(document);
    StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(new File(xmlFilePath));



    transformer.transform(domSource, streamResult);

    System.out.println("Done creating XML File");


    }
    catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
        pce.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TransformerException tfe) {
        tfe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

this is the code i have written.....

This part is coming as a list inside Targetvalue

```
     /output1/output1/output1/output13           
    /output1/output1/output1/output14                  
    /output1/output1/output13/output12            
    /output1/output1/output13/output16
```

And

```
    /input12/bunny
    /input12/bunny
    /input12/bunny
    /input12/bunny
```

in the the list Source values

surce value and the target value has link.. means first value of source is connected with first value of target.. 2nd value of source connected with 2nd value of target.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><xsl:stylesheet><xsl:template match="/"><output1><output1><output1><output13><xsl:value-of select="/input12/bunny"/></output13></output1></output1></output1><output1><output1><output1><output14><xsl:value-of select="/input12/no"/></output14></output1></output1></output1><output1><output1><output13><output12><xsl:value-of select="/input12/ok"/><xsl:value-of select="/input12/honey"/></output12></output13></output1></output1></xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>
```

this is getting generated.........

but what i want is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<xsl:stylesheet>
<xsl:template match="/">
<output1>
   <output1>
     <output1>
      <output13>
        <xsl:value-of select="/input12/bunny"/>
      </output13>
      <output14>
        <xsl:value-of select="/input12/no"/>
      </output14>
     </output1>

     <output13>
       <output12>
         <xsl:value-of select="/input12/ok"/>
       </output12>
       <output16>
         <xsl:value-of select="/input12/honey"/>
       </output16>
     </output13>

   </output1>
 </output1>
```

Comment: Seems both your key and value are String. What exactly you mean by comparing? Do you want to sort by key or what operation you want to perform on map?

Comment: i have already sorted the map. Now i want to create xml tag. as 1st output1 is same one output1 tag will be generated, next inside this another output1 will be generate as all are same, then one output1 and output13.. inside output 1  ..it will be  output13 and output14

Comment: @proton I think it helps all of us if you add how the resulting XML is supposed to look like for the given strings.